# Guardar arreglo unidimensional en uno bidimensional

Tags: java, array

tengo un array unidimensional como el siguiente:

```
Posición: 1 = [12345678-0C, 12345678-0, Paterno Materno Nombres, correo1@mail.cl, 56912345678, Direccion personal, Nombre de ciudad, 1-9, Paterno2 Materno2 Nombres2, correo2@mail.cl, 56987654321, Direccion 2, Direccion 3, Ciudad 2, Estado 1, 5550000, Chile, 1, 1, 87600012345, Banco 1, Chile, 037, BSCHCLRM]
Posición: 2 = [4-3C, 4-3, Cliente 4 de prueba, cliente4@dimarsa.cl, 56-65-2345678, Direccion 4 de prueba, PUERTO VARAS]
Posición: 3 = [5-1C, 5-1, cliente 5 de prueba, cliente5@dimarsa.cl, 56-65-2456789, direccion 5 de prueba, PUERTO VARAS, 3-3, Nombre completo contacto 3, notiene@sinserver.cl, 988776655, Direccion 3 de contacto]
Posición: 4 = [6-KC, 6-K, Cliente 6 de prueba, cliente6@dimarsa.cl, 56-65-2987654, Direccion 6 de prueba, PUERTO MONTT, 4-4, Nombre completo contacto 4, notiene@sinserver.cl, 955667788, Direccion 4 de contacto, Direccion DESPACHO, Ciudad DESPACHO, Region DESPACHO, 5550000, Chile]
```

El cual sale de la variable `contenedor[]`

```
for (int j = 1; i <= contenedor.length; j++) {
   if(j == 5) {
      break;
   }
   System.out.println("Posición: " + j + " = " + contenedor[j]);
}
```

Lo que hago actualmente es guardar el dato `[1]` en un array `datoUnico[]` de la siguiente forma:

```
String datoUnico[] = contenedor[1].split(",");
```

Imprimiendo lo siguiente:

```
Posicion: 0 = [12345678-0C
Posicion: 1 =  12345678-0
Posicion: 2 =  Paterno Materno Nombres
Posicion: 3 =  correo1@mail.cl
Posicion: 4 =  56912345678
Posicion: 5 =  Direccion personal
Posicion: 6 =  Nombre de ciudad
Posicion: 7 =  1-9
Posicion: 8 =  Paterno2 Materno2 Nombres2
Posicion: 9 =  correo2@mail.cl
Posicion: 10 =  56987654321
Posicion: 11 =  Direccion 2
Posicion: 12 =  Direccion 3
Posicion: 13 =  Ciudad 2
Posicion: 14 =  Estado 1
Posicion: 15 =  5550000
Posicion: 16 =  Chile
Posicion: 17 =  1
Posicion: 18 =  1
Posicion: 19 =  87600012345
Posicion: 20 =  Banco 1
Posicion: 21 =  Chile
Posicion: 22 =  037
Posicion: 23 =  BSCHCLRM]
```

Con el código:

```
for (int n = 0; n <= (datoUnico.length - 1); n++) {
   System.out.print("Posicion: " + n + " = ");
   System.out.println(datoUnico[n]);
}
```

Ahora, lo que me gustaría hacer sería guardar `contenedor[n]` en `datoUnico[n][m]`, de forma que pase de un array unidimensional a uno bidimensional, para ello, tengo el siguiente código:

```
String datoUnico[][] = new String[contenedor.length - 1][];

for(int n = 0; n <= (contenedor.length - 1); n++) {
   for (int m = 0; ; m++) {
      datoUnico[n][m] = contenedor[m].split(",");
      datoUnico[n][m] = datoUnico[n][m].replace("[", "");
      datoUnico[n][m] = datoUnico[n][m].replace("]", "");
      datoUnico[n][m] = datoUnico[n][m].replace(" ", "");
   }
}
```

Sin embargo, en `contenedor[m].split(",")` me tira el error `Type mismatch: cannot convert from String[] to String`.

¿Qué me estaría faltando? revisé en varias partes, pero solo aparece el cómo pasar de bidimensional a unidimensional, y lo que necesito es hacer lo contrario.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

el error te da porque estas tratando de guardar en una celda de tu arreglo bidimencional datoUnico el resultado de un split que es un arreglo cuando deberías guardar el resultado del split en una fila del arreglo bidimencional no en la celda. Se soluciona sacando el split del segundo for.

```
String datoUnico[][] = new String[contenedor.length ][];
    for(int n = 0; n <= (contenedor.length - 1); n++) {
        datoUnico[n] = contenedor[n].split(",");
        for (int m = 0;m< datoUnico[n].length; m++) {
            datoUnico[n][m] = datoUnico[n][m].replace("[", "");
            datoUnico[n][m] = datoUnico[n][m].replace("]", "");
            datoUnico[n][m] = datoUnico[n][m].replace(" ", "");
            System.out.println(datoUnico[n][m]);
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 2):

necesitas primero declarar el tamaño correcto de las filas del `array bidimensional` ,en tu caso son 4 que es igual al array `contenedor.lenght`

```
String [][] datoUnico=new String[contenedor.length][];
```

si

`contenedor[0].split(",");` te devuelve un array,solo necesitas utilizar esa lógica para guardar los datos por fila en el arrayBidimensional(recuerda que los indices en un array parten de 0)

```
//aqui estas guardando cada array generado por split(",") en su fila especifica dentro del array bidimensional
    for (int i=0;i<datoUnico.length;i++ ) {
        datoUnico[i]=contenedor[i].split(",");
    }
```

solo te queda imprimir

```
for (int i=0;i<datoUnico.length;i++ ) {
    for (int j=0;j<datoUnico[i].length;j++ ) {
        System.out.print("posicion "+(j)+"   "+datoUnico[i][j]+"\n");
    }System.out.println("");
}
}
```

Comment: Gracias! lo terminé ajustando según tus indicaciones